# AssertJ: How to return the actual exception when using method assertThatThrownBy

Tags: java, junit5, assertj

I am migrating from JUnit 5 and Hamcrest Assertions to AssertJ and I can't figure out the right method for extracting the actual exception from the executable. Here is a JUnit/Hamcrest example:

```
var result = assertThrows(MyException.class, () -> this.objectUnderTest.someMethod(param1, param2, param3));
assertThat(result.getError().getErrorCode(), equalTo(someValue));
assertThat(result.getError().getDescription(), equalTo("someString"));
```

What I would like to have is smth. like (AssertJ)

```
var result = assertThatThrownBy(() -> this.objectUnderTest.someMethod(param1, param2, param3))
 .isInstanceOf(MyException.class);
assertThat(result.getError().getErrorCode(), equalTo(someValue));
assertThat(result.getError().getDescription(), equalTo("someString"));
```

But as of the AssertJ version `3.21.0` the `assertThatThrownBy` method gives me an instance of `AbstractThrowableAssert<?, ? extends Throwable>` class and I can't find any method which would give me then the `MyException` instance. So for now I ended up using another method and casting manually to `MyException`:

```
Throwable throwable = Assertions.catchThrowable(() -> this.objectUnderTest.doFilterInternal(param1, param2, param3));
MyException exception = (MyException) throwable;
assertThat(exception.getError().getErrorCode(), equalTo(someValue));
assertThat(exception.getError().getDescription(), equalTo("someString"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AssertJ offers two styles for checking custom exceptions:

- [BDD style](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-exception-assertions-bdd-style) with [`catchThrowableOfType`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html#catchThrowableOfType(org.assertj.core.api.ThrowableAssert.ThrowingCallable,java.lang.Class))
- [Single statement style](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-exception-assertions-assertThatExceptionOfType) with [`assertThatExceptionOfType`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html#assertThatExceptionOfType(java.lang.Class))

Keeping the style of your example, you can write the following with `catchThrowable`:

```
Throwable throwable = catchThrowable(() -> this.objectUnderTest.someMethod(param1, param2, param3));

assertThat(throwable)
  .asInstanceOf(InstanceOfAssertFactories.throwable(MyException.class))
  .extracting(MyException::getError)
  .returns(1, from(Error::getErrorCode))
  .returns("something", from(Error::getDescription));
```

or, with `catchThrowableOfType`:

```
MyException exception = catchThrowableOfType(() -> this.objectUnderTest.someMethod(param1, param2, param3), MyException.class);

assertThat(exception)
  .extracting(MyException::getError)
  .returns(1, from(Error::getErrorCode))
  .returns("something", from(Error::getDescription));
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```java
> var result = assertThatThrownBy(() ->
> this.objectUnderTest.someMethod(param1, param2, param3)) 
> .isInstanceOf(MyException.class);
> assertThat(result.getError().getErrorCode(), equalTo(someValue));
> assertThat(result.getError().getDescription(), equalTo("someString"));
> ```

The AssertJ way is following:

```java
assertThatExceptionOfType(MyException.class)
        .isThrownBy(() -> this.objectUnderTest.someMethod(param1, param2, param3))
        .satisfies(ex -> assertThat(ex.getError().getErrorCode()).isEqualTo(someValue));
```